# Android-When "Profile GPU rendering" not working for game apps

Tags: android, performance, graphics

The "Profile GPU rendering" option on Android phones works fine with normal apps like "Settings"/"Calendar",.etc. But when I was trying to profile with some game apps like Unity3D sort of games, it didn't work, neither using on screen bars or dumpsys gfxinfo, nothing came out. Have anyone encounter this before? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the option is for profiling GPU rendering of View UI content, i.e. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html . There are vendor-specific tools for profiling OpenGL ES.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main code paths in android

1. Android Framework (Java language)
2. Android NDK (C/C++ language)

The Android Framework is built up with UI and tooling to help you write applications easily and successfully. The tools like "profile GPU Rendering" specifically report information about how the framework is drawing widgets (like buttons / pictures ) to the screen.

The Android NDK, on the other hand, is pretty much a no-mans-land. There's no direct tooling provided here by the Android team to diagnose and debug issues.

Most games are built using the Android NDK, because they don't require the Framework, and can get directly to using C/C++ code (in the case of Unity and other 3rd party rendering engines, they are dominantly built on C++ code).

As such, check out 3rd party profiling tools like [Intel GPA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/gpa), or [Nvidia PerfHud](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/android-debugging-high-performance-applications)